# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when using getGeneratedKeys

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

When I am using the following query it works.

```
query = "INSERT INTO MLRL1_PSR_MASTER (PROJECT_ID,FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,TEMPLATE_ID,TEMPLATE_TYPE,UPLOADED_BY,PSR_SLABID) " +
        " select '"+projectId+"' , FROM_DATE , TO_DATE,'"+templateId+"','"+tempType+"','"+user.getUserID()+"', "+slabId+
        " from MLRL1_PSR_SLABS where SLAB_ID="+slabId+" ";

stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query, new String[] { "ID" });
stmt.executeUpdate();
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
```

but if i use same query with getGeneratedKeys() like:

```
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query, new String[] { "ID" });
stmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

while (rs.next()) {
    masterId = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

I get an error

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

`stmt` is `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, Code compliance is 1.6 and JRE is 1.7.67 Oracle Driver is odbc6 and database is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0

Comment: Print the generated SQL Statement and run it manually. I'm pretty sure you will see the error yourself. You shouldn't be concatenating user input in the first place, use  a `PreparedStatement` instead

Comment: Do you get the different behaviour with exactly the same generated string using the same concatenated (!) values - or are they different? Do any of them contain quotes or commas or anything else that would confuse the parser (which wouldn't be a problem if you were using bind variables)?

Comment: @horse: Print the generated SQL Statement and run it manually: It runs smooth.. On my SQL Developer.@Aelx Poole: I know that I used prepared statement but in process to find out issue i tried without setXXX() and it is still not working.

Comment: I can't replicate this. Which version of Java, which driver (and version), and which version of Oracle are you using? Is `stmt` a `java.sql.PreparedStatement` or something else?

Comment: @Alex: stmt is java.sql.PreparedStatement, Code compliance is 1.6 and JRE is 1.7.67 Oracle Driver is odbc6 and database is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0

Comment: I'm testing with pretty close to that. To get a stupid/offensive question out of the way, you're sure the error is coming from that `prepareStatement()` call - you haven't added other code later, say to use `masterid` in another statement? Or is the error actually thrown by the `getGeneratedKeys()` call? Can you add a complete example that demonstrates the error, maybe?

Comment: Make sure that the variable slabId is not null or empty in that statement. If it is null/empty then the query would just end like - `WHERE SLAB_ID=` . This might give you that error that sql command not properly ended. As AlexPoole said, use bind variables

Comment: Guys sysout for query runs on raptor/SQL developer ..

Comment: Have you tried adding a trailing semi-colon just as a sanity check?

Answer (score -3):

I think the syntax is not correct. You probably need to add 'VALUES' in your query. The insert query should look like - INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES ();

Comment: I think the syntax is right, the OP is using `INSERT INTO table(...) SELECT ... FROM othertable` syntax

Comment: Syntax is correct. Speciall when I am saying it works without autogenerated keys.